# wsdl is not getting generated from java class

Tags: java, maven, wsdl, jax-ws

iam generating wsdl from java class using maven java2wsdl generation. Also iam not getting any exception. Below is the pom.xml . Please can anyone suggest how to fix it.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.facial</groupId>
  <artifactId>facedetections</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>facedetections Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
      <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
      <version>5.1.6</version>
    </dependency>         
    <dependency>
      <groupId>gov.nist.math</groupId>
      <artifactId>jama</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.media</groupId>
      <artifactId>jmf</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.1e</version>
    </dependency>
    </dependencies>

  <build>
    <finalName>facedetections</finalName>
    <pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>deploy</phase>
            <configuration>
              <tasks>
                <target name="-post-compile">
                    <copy file="C:\Program Files\JMF2.1.1e\lib\jmf.properties" todir="E:\path\to\local\repo\javax\media\jmf\2.1.1e\"/>
                </target>
                <!--
                  Place any Ant task here. You can add anything
                  you can add between <target> and </target> in a
                  build.xml.
                -->

              </tasks>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
              <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin> 
       <plugin>
           <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
           <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>2.3.1</version>
           <configuration>
               <source>1.6</source>
               <target>1.6</target>
           </configuration>
       </plugin>


        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>generate-wsdl</id>
                    <phase>process-classes</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>wsgen</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <sei>com.facial.facedetection.ws.FaceDetectionV001<!-- fully qualified class name goes here --></sei>
                        <genWsdl>true</genWsdl>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>generate-stubs</id>
                    <phase>process-classes</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>wsimport</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <wsdlDirectory>target/jaxws/wsgen/wsdl</wsdlDirectory>
                        <wsdlFiles>                   
                            <wsdlFile><!-- class name goes here -->Service.wsdl</wsdlFile>
                        </wsdlFiles>
                        <!-- *** you need the next line to set the wsdlLocation in the generated stubs *** -->
                        <wsdlLocation>http://localhost:8080/test</wsdlLocation> 
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

Also in build console, there is no any log of jave to wsdl generation. Below is the console log.

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building facedetections Maven Webapp 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) @ facedetections ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 2 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.1:compile (default-compile) @ facedetections ---
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding Cp1252, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 26 source files to C:\Users\LENOVO\workspace\JavaCV-Harr\face-detection\facedetections\target\classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:testResources (default-testResources) @ facedetections ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\LENOVO\workspace\JavaCV-Harr\face-detection\facedetections\src\test\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ facedetections ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.10:test (default-test) @ facedetections ---
[INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO] Surefire report directory: C:\Users\LENOVO\workspace\JavaCV-Harr\face-detection\facedetections\target\surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-war-plugin:2.1.1:war (default-war) @ facedetections ---
[INFO] Packaging webapp
[INFO] Assembling webapp [facedetections] in [C:\Users\LENOVO\workspace\JavaCV-Harr\face-detection\facedetections\target\facedetections]
[INFO] Processing war project
[INFO] Copying webapp resources [C:\Users\LENOVO\workspace\JavaCV-Harr\face-detection\facedetections\src\main\webapp]
[INFO] Webapp assembled in [1998 msecs]
[INFO] Building war: C:\Users\LENOVO\workspace\JavaCV-Harr\face-detection\facedetections\target\facedetections.war
[WARNING] Warning: selected war files include a WEB-INF/web.xml which will be ignored 
(webxml attribute is missing from war task, or ignoreWebxml attribute is specified as 'true')
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.3.1:install (default-install) @ facedetections ---
[INFO] Installing C:\Users\LENOVO\workspace\JavaCV-Harr\face-detection\facedetections\target\facedetections.war to C:\path\to\local\repo\com\facial\facedetections\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\facedetections-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
[INFO] Installing C:\Users\LENOVO\workspace\JavaCV-Harr\face-detection\facedetections\pom.xml to C:\path\to\local\repo\com\facial\facedetections\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\facedetections-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 20.676s
[INFO] Finished at: Sat Aug 31 22:13:53 IST 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 10M/25M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your plugin invocation:

```
 <plugins>
   <plugin>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
      <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   </plugin>
 </plugins>
```

also *outside* `pluginManagement`.

PluginManagement in the pomfile is for configuration of plugin runs (for child modules as well), but the plugin won't be actually run in current build if it not declared also in main plugin element

Comment: sure; whatever plugin definition you put in `<build><pluginManagement><plugins>` is configuration for that particular plugin (that can be inherited in child projects). The plugins whose executions are actually attached to the build are those listed in `<build><plugins>` element.

Comment: thus, you can alternatively 1. move the jaxws plugin declaration outside `<pluginManagement>` or 2. leave it there and add a new declaration inside `<build><plugins>` (only artifactId and groupId, all other properties will be read from pluginManagement)